# Repository.save only commit when creating, not updating

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a microservice using Spring Boot, Hibernate and Spring Data Jpa. The thing is that when I am trying to save an entity, it commits the transaction only when the entity is new, but not when updating it (when the id is not null). It is strange because I am using the same code when creating or updating an entity.

I activated the logs, and I can see the insert into statement only when creating the entity. Any hint?

```
@Transactional
public class MyEntityService {

    @UserCanCud
    public Entity save(final Entity entity) {
        Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity to store cannot be null");
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

PS: When I return the entity, it is the entity "updated", but if I retrieve it again, the values are not updated.

UserCanCud checks in the database if the user is allowed to do cud operations for that entity.

Comment: Please provide more information. Configs? How the code is called? Where transaction is opened?

Comment: May I know why the `entity` object is marked `final`?

Comment: Hi harshavmb, there is no specific reason for that, do you think that that could be the problem?

Comment: If there is no specific reason, can you remove and try?

Comment: Can you please show us the save implementation of the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fould the problem.... The pojo had the annotation @Immutable.